# Override Checkout complete page in drupal commerce

Tags: drupal-7, checkout, drupal-commerce

I want to change the content of the checkout complete page in drupal commerce but not able to figure out where to change .I am not able to find the hook_form_alter for this , someone please guide me and help me in updating the content of the checkout page.

i.e Page where it says your order number is XYZ....

Answer (score 1):

The "Checkout complete" page is customizable at /admin/commerce/config/checkout

Answer (score 0):

Even i did face a similar problem. The simplest way to overcome this is to create a new checkout page as per your requirements & use rules module to redirect on that page.

Hope this helps you